# Is this multivariable function continuous?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

My function is: $$f\left(x,\:y\right)\:=\:y\left(sin\left(\frac{1}{x-1}\right)\right)\::\:x\:\ne 1$$
$$f\left(x,\:y\right)\:=\:0\::\:x\:=1$$
The question sounds like: "Are this functions continuous?" (There are few exercises and that is one of the functions).

It doesnt say anything about the coordinate of y in which i should check its continuousness.

So is it right to say that on (1,0) it is, because: $$\lim _{\left(x,y\right)\to \left(1,0\right)}y\left(sin\left(\frac{1}{x-1}\right)\right)\:=\:0$$ as product of bounded sin and limit 0.

and in each other point it isnt continuous because it doesnt exist ?

Comment: **Hint:** If $f$ is continuous, then in particular $g(x)=f(x+1,1)$ should be continuous too (because the composition of continuous functions is continuous). Is it?

Comment: What can you say about continuity at $(x,\,y)=(1,\,1)?$

Comment: at (1,1) seems to be not, because the sin func is getting crazy there, she goes up and down at very high rate.

Comment: "she goes up and down at very high rate"

Comment: the first function that you gave is, its sin(1).

Comment: Ok, I got it, if it is continuous then the limit must be for any path 0, but it isnt, for exmaple for the path you gave (x+1,1). Alright!